# devtools::check() error: loading failed for 'i386'

Tags: r, devtools

When running `devtools::check()`, it works fine with message

"0 errors, 0 warnings, 0 NOTEs" in R 3.5.3 version,

but after updating to version 3.6.0, the following error occurs.

Same error occurs in `R CMD check`.
I have already installed Rtools35.

```
-- R CMD check -------------------------------------------
-  using log directory 'C:/Users/nhkim1302/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpUpSHYz/promotionImpact.Rcheck' (595ms)
-  using R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
-  using platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32 (64-bit)
-  using session charset: CP949
-  using options '--no-manual --as-cran'
√  checking for file 'promotionImpact/DESCRIPTION' ... 
-  checking extension type ... Package
-  this is package 'promotionImpact' version '0.1.2'
-  package encoding: UTF-8
√  checking package namespace information ... 
√  checking package dependencies (1.1s)
√  checking if this is a source package ... 
√  checking if there is a namespace
√  checking for executable files (346ms)
√  checking for hidden files and directories ... 
√  checking for portable file names ... 
E  checking whether package 'promotionImpact' can be installed (11.9s)
   Installation failed.
   See 'C:/Users/nhkim1302/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpUpSHYz/promotionImpact.Rcheck/00install.out' for details.

   See
     'C:/Users/nhkim1302/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpUpSHYz/promotionImpact.Rcheck/00check.log'
   for details.

Warning in readChar(path, nchars = file.info(path)$size, ...) :
  can only read in bytes in a non-UTF-8 MBCS locale
-- R CMD check results --------------------------------------- promotionImpact 0.1.2 ----
Duration: 14.1s

> checking whether package 'promotionImpact' can be installed ... ERROR
  See below...

-- Install failure ----------------------------------------------------------------------

* installing *source* package 'promotionImpact' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
*** arch - i386
system(cmd, intern = !verbose)에서 경고가 발생했습니다 : ## warning occurs
  명령 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.0/bin/i386/R CMD SHLIB file3b7456314194.cpp 2> file3b7456314194.cpp.err.txt'의 실행으로 상태 1가 되었습니다 ## Execution of the command resulted in a status of 1.
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'prophet':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'prophet', details:
  call: sink(type = "output")
  error: 유효하지 않은 커넥션입니다 ## invalid connection
Error : package 'prophet' could not be loaded
에러: 로딩에 실패했습니다 ## ERROR: loading failed
실행이 정지되었습니다 ## Execution stopped
*** arch - x64
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
* removing 'C:/Users/nhkim1302/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpUpSHYz/promotionImpact.Rcheck/promotionImpact'

1 error x | 0 warnings √ | 0 notes √
```

Here's my session info.

`session_info()`
- Session info ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value
 version  R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
 os       Windows >= 8 x64
 system   x86_64, mingw32
 ui       RStudio
 language (EN)
 collate  Korean_Korea.949
 ctype    Korean_Korea.949
 tz       Asia/Seoul
 date     2019-05-14

Comment: can you translate the korean error message?

Comment: I wrote them as a comments next to ##.